# erlang tuples to list to maps from a text file

Tags: erlang

I am trying to read data from text file put the tuples from the file into a list and then map them the code is as follows I am new to erlang and dont know what I am doing wrong:

```
-module(exchange).
-export([start/0]).
start()->
A= file:consult("calls.txt"),
B=tuple_to_list(A),
io:fwrite("~p~n",[maps:from_list([B])]).
```

It gives me the error :

```
 5> c(exchange).     
  {ok,exchange}
  26> exchange:start().
      ** exception error: bad argument
         in function  maps:from_list/1
         called as maps:from_list([[ok,
                                   [{john,[jill,joe,bob]},
                                    {jill,[bob,joe,bob]},
                                    {sue,[jill,jill,jill,bob,jill]},
                                    {bob,[john]},
                                    {joe,[sue]}]]])
     in call from exchange:start/0 (exchange.erl, line 10)
```

Please help me here . Thank you .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`file:consult/2` returns `{ok, Terms}` on success so this should work:

```
{ok, A} = file:consult("calls.txt"),
io:fwrite("~p~n", [maps:from_list(A)]).
```

Comment: It didnt worked I tried here the data in the text file :

{john, [jill,joe,bob]}.
{jill, [bob,joe,bob]}.
{sue, [jill,jill,jill,bob,jill]}.
{bob, [john]}.
{joe, [sue]}.

after every dot a new line starts

Comment: ok I was still using the tuple to list conversion if I dont do that its working fine 

 exchange:start().
#{bob => [john],
  jill => [bob,joe,bob],
  joe => [sue],
  john => [jill,joe,bob],
  sue => [jill,jill,jill,bob,jill]}
ok
I get this output I want to get the first person from eacg tuple and make a call to each person in the list in that tuple like send some message to each person from first person and then get a reply back .